# Powershell: Preserve newline characters from terraform plan when setting output as variable

Tags: powershell

I am trying to pass the output of a terraform plan in to a pull request in a "readable" fashion, but I'm finding when I set the output from my plan as a variable it removes all newlines.

Example with write-host(which is how it is being shown in my PR:

```
$blah = terraform show -no-color blah.tfplan
write-host $blah
   Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:   + create  Terraform will perform the following actions:    # aws_ecr_repository.blah will be created   + resource "aws_ecr_repository" "blah" {       + arn                  = (known after apply)       + id                   = (known after apply)       + image_tag_mutability = "MUTABLE"       + name                 = "name"       + registry_id          = (known after apply)       + repository_url       = (known after apply)        + image_scanning_configuration {           + scan_on_push = true         }     }  Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

Example just writing the variable which preserves all of the newlines:

```
$blah

Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution
plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_ecr_repository.blah will be created
  + resource "aws_ecr_repository" "blah" {
      + arn                  = (known after apply)
      + id                   = (known after apply)
      + image_tag_mutability = "MUTABLE"
      + name                 = "name"
      + registry_id          = (known after apply)
      + repository_url       = (known after apply)

      + image_scanning_configuration {
          + scan_on_push = true
        }
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

I have also tested to see if any newline characters are showing in my variable and they are not.  So how can it display cleanly with different lines....but not have any newline characters?

```
$blah.contains("`n")
False
$blah.contains("`r")
False
```

Comment: I'd guess that `$blah.GetType().Name` returns `String[]`? Then use `Write-Host ($blah -join [System.Environment]::NewLine)`.

Comment: It actually returns Object[]. I would have expected it to be a string as well.  Which knowing that I just piped my variable to `Out-String` and it now is a string with all of my formatting!

Comment: Then check `$blah | ForEach-Object {$_.GetType().Name} | Group-Object`. Please [edit] your question to update your [mcve] (share `$blah | ConvertTo-Json`).